# Can't select bones in weightpaint mode

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I watched a lot of tutorials but I don't know what to do further.

When I go into weightpaint mode it looks lie in the picture or the bone have an orange outline.

I tried to select the bone by right clicking, left clicking with ctrl and shift. I even tried to select the bone by name.

But it doesn't work.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to change "bone" during weight paint is to select the corresponding vertex group.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select the bone when the object you are trying to weight-paint is selected. You must first select the bone.

Comment: But then I cant go to wieghtpaint mode

Comment: You select the bone in pose mode, and then select the object. It should show up.

Comment: Thank you it helped.